# Mutual SSL Authentication in Azure App Service

Tags: azure, authentication, ssl

I am using Azure App Service to access a webservice hosted elsewhere.  The webservice requires mutual TLS Authentication.

I have been given the public certificate from the provider of the webservice but where do I install this public certificate in Azure?  In a traditional server environment, I would install in the certificate store.  But in Azure, do I install it on the application gateway?  or the Vault?  How does Azure app service know where the certificate is installed and present it?

Answer (score 0):

Private and Public certificates can be uploaded to Azure Web App: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate?tabs=apex%2Cportal

Code running in Azure Web App can access those certificates in different ways, it depends on what language and runtime your application is using: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code

In regards to your other questions:

"do I install it on the application gateway"?

From what I understand, your application is going to make outgoing calls to a webservice hosted elsewhere. Azure Web App outgoing traffic does not go through Application Gateway - so no, in your case storing certificate in Azure Web App and accessing it from the code is a good solution.

"or the Vault"? Azure Web App can also store certificates in Azure Key Vault. Your code could also connect to Azure Key Vault directly, bypassing Azure Web App key store altogether.

Finally, "How does Azure app service know where the certificate is installed and present it?" Please see the first two links I provided.